# FQL Location post json output

Tags: php, arrays, json, facebook-fql

I have a question (I think it is a easy one but I can't find out how).
I am using the location post in Facebook Query Languagr, the `print_r` output is

`Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => some id [message] => some message )`

`[1] => Array ( [id] => some id [message] => some message )`

The question is how can I output just id, or just message?

I have tried:

```
foreach($test as $test2) {
$test2['id'];
}
```

and 3 `foreach` loops but it will not work, I hope someone can help me.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following foreach loop to get all of your id's and messages

```
foreach($test['data'] as $data) {
    $id = $data['id'];
    $message = $data['message'];

}
```